# Is it possible for secure third-party peering at wireless access points?

Tags: wireless, security, access-point, ad-hoc-wireless, peering

If the question title doesn't make sense, please forgive me, I'm not a networking person.  I will try to describe what I mean:

When you view your available networks on your computer, some are your service and some belong to others/neighbors.  Theoretically you could connect to your neighbors' if you had a deal with/trusted them.

One could imagine ways to make this beneficial for both you and your neighbor.  You could make a few extra bucks by someone else using your service, and this person could avoid signing contracts and dealing with ISP's.

But the usefulness is only as good as your relationship with your neighbor.  One wouldn't want to engage in something with a bad neighbor, much less a perfect stranger.  What if they hack you or give you a virus?

I'm wondering if this is necessarily the case.  Is there any way to make WAP's secure?  What if both owner has set up the WAP to use a CJDNS NAT gateway?

It's possible that I've confused some concepts here, so please feel free to be blunt with your answers.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Are you asking how to limit/filter traffic coming from your neighbor? Are you asking how to prevent your neighbor from using your ISP in way you don't want?

Comment: @RonTrunk  I guess I'm asking how to limit/filter traffic from a neighbor.  Basically, how can you share your wireless network with your neighbor without them giving you viruses?

Comment: It can be done, but it might be cheaper for them to have their own ISP connection,

Comment: @RonTrunk  That's probably the case, but I'm more interested in the theoretical possibility and what it would require.

Comment: @RonTrunk  What would make doing this prohibitively expensive?

Comment: Commercial grade WAPs can isolate/restrict/filter traffic, but they're considerably more expensive than home WAPs.

Answer (score 1):

If your home wap has vlan capability you can create two SSID's. Assign each SSID to a vlan. Then, assign ACLS (access control lists) to allow them to get to the Internet but block them from your addresses.

Some home WAPs also have guest mode and features that don't let computers talk to other computers on the same network.

To add... you can get a robust firmware for alot of home style WAPS like [these --> click](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)